# Create a log using trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I created a table name as log to store some log after the table 'lançamento' is changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_UPDATE
AFTER INSERT
ON lançamento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log (`Data`, `Operação`, `Token do lançamento`)
    VALUES (NEW.`Momento do lançamento`, 'INSERT', NEW.`Token do lançamento`);
END;
```

On this code above I'm storing the inserted values in the table log but i got an error syntax near to line 4. I use MySQL PHPMYADMIN

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different `DELIMITER` from semicolon `;`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_UPDATE
AFTER INSERT
ON lançamento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log (`Data`, `Operação`, `Token do lançamento`)
    VALUES (NEW.`Momento do lançamento`, 'INSERT', NEW.`Token do lançamento`);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Or just don't use `BEGIN` and `END`, since the body of the trigger is only one statement.